# Can the Flash see the future now?

Tags: dc, the-new-52, the-flash

In Issue #2 of the Flash (Oct 2011) it shows Barry tapping into the Speed Force with just his brain and not his body. Through this he's able to see what will happen in the near future to all the people in his surroundings.

Is this confirmation that he can now see the future? Is this a new superpower?

Comment: Didn't you just answer the question?

Comment: No, I'm asking if its confirmation of a new power, or just something Barry did as a fluke.

Answer (score 18):

#### No. The Flash is not using a supernatural ability to see the future. This is not a new power at all. It is a new and different way of depicting how the Flash controls his perception of time, space and his relationship to the world at large. Being as fast as he is, he appears to violate causality appearing to be everywhere at once. He isn't but his speed can give him the illusion of simultaneity.

Since Barry Allen has been gone from the DCU for some time, the book is trying to present a new take on the character and his powers. Depending on the writer, how the Flash handles [relative simultaneity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity) (how things appear to happen simultaneously in relationship to the viewer) varies widely.

In The Flash #2, the Flash (as Barry Allen) is standing outside of a storefront where a robbery is about to/has/will happen. He is shown experiencing a moment where he is able to perceive a series of events that will/has happened and then decides to make minor changes to the series of events so different results ensue.

[image: Barry experiencing a relative view of potential futures]

Does the Flash predict the future? No, the Flash lives at the edge of relative time, so he can tell the most liable future from a series of events based on his position in the decisions being made. He is able to parse this information to make the right decision at the right time and from the perspective of someone on the outside of the event, he has dealt with every event apparently at the same time.

[image: He decides which events work for him and acts]

Looking at the final image, it does not resemble every permutation he conceived of, just the ones he decided would be the most effective at solving the problem without appearing to be doing anything untoward.

[image: The outcomes play out similar to what he expected]

This extension of his temporal sense is not a new power, but a different way of showing how he controls his view of time in relationship to himself. Judging from his surprise, he may have never looked at his powers this way before and is experiencing his speed powers differently since his rebirth. See more at: [How does the Flash perceive time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5933/2765)?

Answer (score -2):

But the The Flash says, "I can see everything 'before' it happens'. He can see the future / multiple futures and take a separate track

Comment: Can you back this up by providing a source for this quote?